# Remove SSO Saml Response redirection page in Wso2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to remove **saml sso redirection page** from Authentication flow in **wso2 IS 5.5.0**.

Below Content on page:

You are now redirected to URL If the redirection fails, please click the post button' is displayed before displaying the Demo page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove the redirection page. You need SSO redirection, but still, you can do customization for the page by following [customizing sso redirection page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Customizing+the+SSO+Redirection+Page)

The reason to have this redirection page is when the response comes after SAML request, the client will submit with username/password and, the SAML response which comes through IS should be posted back to SP, that's where you need auto post re-direction logic.

Comment: Thanks Nilasini, we customize it as per our contents.